# Vector Infographic - Why does it render differently in the web browser?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, website-design, fonts, svg, information-graphics

I made an infographic in *Adobe Illustrator*, and saved it as a `.svg` file. But then **when I tried to open it in the Google Chrome browser, some of the fonts and some italicized fonts were not even italicized. Why is this happening and what is the solution?**

It was `600*1100 pixels` because I had read somewhere that it is a good size to start with.

It actually turned out to be pretty ugly!

Comment: Fonts aren't automatically embedded in an SVG. Read this question for more information: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5162/how-do-i-embed-google-web-fonts-into-an-svg

Comment: I do not have to do anything with the web, I just did not have any thing else to open the SVG, so I used the web browser. Is there any solution other than that stuff because I don't understand that language.

Comment: What is your end-goal with the SVG? Is this for print?

Comment: It's basically for print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way around this is to expand your fonts/any other assets in your SVG that aren't rendering properly when you open it in the browser. What this means is, you need to highlight your text areas and turn them into Illustrator paths instead of leaving them as selectable text.

The easiest way to do this is:

1. Select all of your text
2. Go to `Object` >> `Expand`
3. Hit 'okay'
4. Resave your SVG.

[image]

Comment: This works well for print, but note that for web, you likely don't want to convert type (for accessibility and SEO reasons)

Comment: OP above has stated it's for print.

Answer (score 1):

I would save a backup with fonts active, and then save another version with fonts converted to outline, saved as .svg format for usage on the web.