# svg image looks odd in html page

Tags: inkscape, text, svg, png, html

So I have two of the same images one is a `SVG` and the other one is a `PNG`. I used Inkscape to export the `PNG` from the `SVG`. The dilemma that I am stuck with is that on the `SVG` the blue lines go much farther past the actually text which is something that I do not want to happen and would like the `SVG`
look exactly like to `PNG`.

[image]

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Your font was replaced.**

Compare each character and you will see some slight differences. The browser is responsible for rendering an SVG file. If it doesn't have access to a font, or if it doesn't understand the font specification, it'll revert to a fallback.

The solution is to **convert the text to paths** with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>. This will make your text un-editable, but it will be rendered correctly.

As a general rule, I *always* convert text to paths in SVG files intended for the web. I typically use layers, so that one layer has the editable text. I then duplicate it, hide the original, and do the conversion. This way, I can edit the text again if I need to.

Comment: Unfortunately, this will invalidate some of the advantages of using SVG in the first place, as file size, texts which can be searched for, which can be automatically translated, which can be made audible by tools or transformed otherwise by devices for blind people. Other advantages are, that corrections are more easy on text as text. Saving a backup before transforming have other disadvantages, as more storage space, managing two instead of one file, determining the workflow ...

Comment: Oh, after reading again, I see that I've overseen the layer with storing the text invisbly. I guess in background color or in a layer below an otherwise background layer?

Comment: @userunknown You are right about the advantages/disadvantages. To the best of my knowledge, there isn't a way to get consistent rendering of text in SVG's produced by Inkscape if the user doesn't have that font on their system, which is why I usually just change the text to paths. Whether or not it's the *best* method, it's one that at least works without headaches. See [Embedding fonts in Inkscape](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/43300/embedding-fonts-in-inkscape)

Comment: I agree and wish, there would be better rendering in browsers. Maybe open reference fonts which could be used via the web or downloaded once to your local platform - if you like or need to use something else, you could still do it. Hopes, fantasies...

Answer (score -1):

First of all - the look of the SVG file depends on how the current software renders it. It means that Explorer can render it differently than Chrome, and FireFox will render it slightly another way... Anyway - if you want to use the svg file in other software than Inkscape - save it as PLAIN svg (and non Inkscape svg)

Comment: Actually using plain SVG [shouldn't make a difference](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Inkscape_SVG_vs._plain_SVG). The difference between plain and Inkscape SVG is that the Inkscape version has some additional namespaced information stored (which is perfectly valid SVG and should be acceptable to any SVG renderer--it'll just be ignored).

Comment: 1. First of all - convert text to path it's not a solution for the WEB.  The text in the web should be indexed! 2. That's right that using plain SVG SHOULDN'T make any difference, but from my experience - it sometimes does (otherwise I wouldn't mention this).

Comment: Keeping the original text in a different layer as I suggest keeps the original text in the file (assuming search engines actually index content in SVG files), which would address #1. For #2, I'd love to see an example (that's a serious, not a snarky, request). I've been using Inkscape for years and never found a benefit to using plain SVG.

Comment: Why "assuming" (in "assuming search engines actually index...")? Example from my everyday workflow - when I import inkscape svg to blender - it must be a plain svg.

Comment: And why are you so disagree with my answer? svg is a markup language, just like html does - of course each browser will render it in it's own specific way, the html pages are not exactly the same in different browsers, it's doesn't mean that you will bake them to images...

Comment: Converting to text to paths in SVGs is not the equivalent of turning a web page into an image. If a font is substituted on a website, for the most part nothing bad will happen. Divs may expand, the page may get longer, etc, but it should be usable. If your font is replace in an SVG, however, it can COMPLETELY change it since the size of text may change while paths will not, which appears to be the issue in this question. Your answer wouldn't solve that problem, hence I disagreed. (FYI, I did not downvote)

Comment: By away  - hiding the editable text in the svg is HIGHLY WRONG - it can be seen like a black SEO by the google, and make you ban. Don't mention that it's just a very unprofessional workaround. It's like baking image with text and put the text in the "alt" tag,,,

Comment: "Converting to text to paths in SVGs is not the equivalent of turning a web page into an image. If a font is substituted on a website, for the most part nothing bad will happen" -  nothiing BAD, OK, but the text is not a text anymore... in our days is very important. And the most important you CAN embed @font-face in your svg document!