# SVG image not displaying CSS base-64 data URL encoded fonts in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg

I'm dynamically generating an SVG that includes text and a font using an embedded base-64 font-face with this method: [How do I embed Google Web Fonts into an SVG?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5162/how-do-i-embed-google-web-fonts-into-an-svg)

```
<defs>
    <style>
        @font-face {
            font-family: 'My Font';
            src: url(data:application/font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64,...) format('woff2');
            font-weight: normal;
            font-style: normal;
        }
        text { 
            font-family: 'My Font', 'Arial', sans-serif; 
        }
    </style>
</defs>
<text>Hello World</text>
```

(Where `...` is the long [base-64 encoded string](http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/Base64Encode/).)

When I download the file and open it in my browser (Chrome), I see the text in the correct font, but **when I open the file in Adobe Illustrator (CS5), the font is not shown**. Instead I see some text in Arial, the fallback font. Is Illustrator picky about some SVG formatting? Does it not know how to parse base-64 data URLs?

Comment: I don't think Illustrator is sold as a *general SVG editor*, much as it also is not a General PDF Editor, which is a similar wrong assumption. Try using a dedicated SVG editor instead.

Comment: Is this a known/documented limitation of Illustrator? I suppose the only option would be a solution that converts the text to shapes (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742148/how-to-convert-text-to-svg-paths); just wondering if that would pose a problem w/ Illustrator also.

Comment: I'd hesitate to call it a *limitation*. Compare with this: Illustrator can both import and export JPEGs; yet no-one dares to call it a JPEG editor (well ... almost no-one). Finding relevant information is hard because your CS5 is outdated by 3 or 4 versions (newer versions should likely do better), and SVG itself may have evolved as well.

Comment: I suppose the best question might be: Is there documentation that explains which SVG v1.1 features are supported in Illustrator?

Comment: For anyone who might know about SVG support in Illustrator: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/45825/which-svg-features-are-supported-by-illustrator