# SVG export for web with fonts

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, svg, browser

I'm trying to export an SVG image, which contains text from illustrator. I want to use it for a website. For SEO and size reasons I don't want to convert typo into vectors. What are the settings I have to use to make it work in all/most browsers. I'm having trouble with Firefox and IE not rendering the fonts correctly.

Comment: What version of IE are you using? Are you using a web-safe font? If not, did you use @font-face CSS declaration to specify fonts? I would check out this question for using font-face on Firefow [How to properly render font-face in Firefox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13504780/how-to-properly-render-font-face-in-firefox). And could you please provide and explanation for the link in your post? I am unsure what I am supposed to look at when going to the link.

Comment: IE10 + IE11. I'm using arial so it should not be a problem. Does Illustrator use @font-face CSS out of the box?

Comment: Illustrator does not use font-face out of the box but that shouldn't matter if you're using a web-safe font like Arial. Can you post your SVG code?

Comment: Changed the link to the SVG Illustrator generated for me. http://power-brands.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/Kernkompetenzen.svg

Comment: My guess is that Firefox and IE do not render the font "ArialMT" but I am pretty sure Arial is the same as ArialMT. I would maybe ask this over at stackoverflow.

Comment: So I have to edit the code manually. What would be the best settings to to save it in Illustrator?

Comment: If you've created a text-based SVG with a web font and want to preserve the text for SEO, here is the best answer I know of: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/124900/45239