# Illustrator: how to embed fonts in SVG file

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, svg, embed

Is there a way to embed a font in an SVG file from Adobe Illustrator, or do I need to convert the fonts to outlines prior to exporting?

Comment: Problem is that support for svg fonts has been removed from most svg renderers

Comment: If you've created a text-based SVG with a web font and want to preserve the text for SEO, here is the best answer I know of: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/124900/45239

Answer (score 2):

The only two options in illustrator for fonts in the "Save as SVG" dialog are "SVG" and "convert to outlines".

The SVG option embeds the fonts, or the system fonts, which you can then swap out in the code with your custom web fonts using a little HTML and/or CSS.

If the graphic and the text are not intertwined or overlapping, you could just do the graphic portion as an SVG, and the text portion via html/css.